# Separating a list into two - Python

Tags: python, list, split, alpha, numeric

For the following code:

```
print("Welcome to the Atomic Weight Calculator.")
compound = input("Enter compund: ")
compound = H5NO3
lCompound = list(compound)
```

I want to create two lists from the list `lCompund`. I want one list for characters and the other for digits. So that I may have something looking like this:

```
n = ['5' , '3']
c = ['H' , 'N' , 'O']
```

Can somebody please help by providing a simple solution?

Comment: Are you aware that those lists don't distinguish between H5NO3 and HN5O3 (say)? You might want to store a 1 for the nitrogen (i.e. N = ['5','1','3']) to get a unique mapping.

Answer (score 6):

Use a list comprehension and filter items using `str.isdigit` and `str.isalpha`:

```
>>> compound = "H5NO3"
>>> [c for c in compound if c.isdigit()]
['5', '3']
>>> [c for c in compound if c.isalpha()]
['H', 'N', 'O']
```

Comment: +0 because you have enough fish you can give them away ;)

Comment: @kojiro I try not to answer such questions, but sometimes it's too hard to resist. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the actual string only once and if the current character is a digit, then store it in the `numbers` otherwise in the `chars`.

```
compound, numbers, chars = "H5NO3", [], []
for char in compound:
    (numbers if char.isdigit() else chars).append(char)
print numbers, chars
```

**Output**

```
['5', '3'] ['H', 'N', 'O']
```

Comment: I can't decide if calling a method on the result of a ternary is elegant or horrifying.

Comment: @Wooble It's horrifying unless the language guarantees the return type of the ternary. :P (My two cents.)